# Regular Expression to get a query string value without using lookbehind

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I want to extract the "en" from the following url so it can be re-written.

> contact/default.aspx?lang=en
>
> /contact/default.aspx?lang=en-us&id=1
>
> /contact/default.aspx?id=1111&lang=en

The above examples should be rewritten as:

> /contact/en/default.aspx

Unfortunately IIS7 does not support lookbehinds so this peice of regex cannot be used:

```
(?<=lang\=)(.+)
```

Any ideas how i can match the value part of the query string?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Is the `lang` part always there? Is it always the last element? Do you always want to insert the `en` (or whatever language was matched) after the last slash?

Comment: I'm want to use regex to get the value after the 'lang=' in a URL. The lang is a query string so it can appear anywhere in the page name.

Comment: Could you also answer the other three questions? What I'm interested in is what exactly you want to do with the "en" once you have it.

Comment: You do not need backtracking or 'lookbehind' for this...

Comment: Oh, and BTW: "Fixer" means "intravenous drug user" in German. Just thought you might want to know :)

Comment: Sure.  After getting the value 'en' i will pass this value into the IIS 7 URL rewriting engine so the URL can be rewritten as 'contact/en/default.aspx'.  Yes i would like to match any value in the lang QS.  eg. /contact/default.aspx?id=1&lang=cn should also be rewritten as '/contact/cn/default.aspx'

Comment: What about `.*?lang=(\w{2}).*` which will capture the language string for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
.*?(&|\?)lang=([^&]+).*
```

and use the capture group 1